# How to remove duplicate words in multiple files and keep only uniq word in initially found file only

Tags: linux

I want to remove all duplicate words in multiple file and keep only one word. How can I do it? Also I want to tell that **contents of the file should not be shorting.**

Example:- Suppose I have 10(from 1.txt to 10.txt) files. Word name ABC is in file number 1 ,4 and 6. Also Word name xyz is in file number 3,5,8,9,10.

```
      I want to remove word ABC from file number 4 and 6 only and keep word ABC in file number 1 only. Same as the for word xyz. I want to keep word xyz only in file number 3.txt and remove from file number 5,8,9,10.txt

     Please give me guidance for the same.

     Thank You.
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the same with files (delete all but the same occurance of size + crc32), but i used a fancy script to filter out the stuff.

You could first use something like `word | sort | uniq` to produce a sorted wordlist for each file.

I would then use an associative array (as in REXX), where

```
 /*  REXX  */
 used. = 0
 do n = 1 to 10; call dofile; end
 exit

 dofile: 
 infile = n'.txt'; outfile = n'.out'
 call stream infile, 'c', 'open read'
 call stream outfile, 'c', 'open write replace'
 do while lines(infile)
   word = linein(infile)
   /* remove the comment markers to make it case insensitive */
   /* word = translate(word) */
   if used.word = 0  
      then do; call lineout outfile, word; used.word = 1; end
  end
  call stream outfile, 'c', 'close'
  call stream infile, 'c', 'close'
  return
```

This particular script maintains a list of all words used in all files.  It reads in a file, and see if the word is already known, or is to be learnt.  If it is to be learnt, then it is remembered, and a copy is written into the .out file of the lesson it was learnt in.  So in your example, 'xyz' is learnt in lessen 3, and is in 3.out, while ABC is learnt in lesson 1, so is in 1.out.

Kind of like learning a language.